# Icon and Title don't appear in AppCombat toolbar

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-toolbar

Icon and Title don't appear in AppCombat toolbar.

[image: toolbar at the emulator]

**This is my xml file for menu:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".HolidayListActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:title="@string/app_name"
android:orderInCategory="100"
app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**This is my resourses file:**

```
<resources>
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.FullScreen" 
 parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/window_background</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@color/window_background</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

**this is my java code:**

```
public class HolidayListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

 ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
   getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

  }

@Override
  protected Fragment createFragment() {
  return new HolidayListFragment();
}

@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_app, menu);
  return true;
}

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
  }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);   }}
```

**This is my layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/holiday_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/holiday_recycler_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/window_background">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using `"windowActionBar">false`?

Comment: Probably to be able use a Toolbar, is it?

Comment: As a second question, which class does `SingleFragmentActivity` extend?

Comment: `SingleFragmentActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity`.
`"windowActionBar">false` doesn't decide anything here.
  Result one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you use toolbar you could describe its components yourself in your layout file.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_icon"
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="toolbat icon"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="toolbar title"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/toolbat_icon"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```